# Boolean equation to check if two integers are equal

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra

Let $x$ and $y$ be two integers. Which function $f(x, y)$ would result in a $1$ if $x = y$ and $0$ if $x \ne y$?

Examples:

1. $x=1, y=2, f(x, y) = 0$
2. $x=4, y=4, f(x, y) = 1$

Comment: Do you want just a function that does what you're asking for, or do you want an expression for what that function would look like?

Comment: Yes, a mathematical function that takes two variables x and y and returns 0 or 1.

Comment: If we arbitrarily define $\frac 0 0 = 1$, then $f(x, y) = \frac{0}{x-y}$ will work.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've gathered, the function you need is the **[Kronecker Delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)**, labeled $\delta$ that is simply defined as :
$$
\delta_{x,y} = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } x \neq y,   \\
1 &\text{if } x = y.   \end{cases}
$$